# Force windows 10 URL shortcut to open in new window

Tags: windows-10, firefox, shortcuts

I have a shortcut on my desktop that links to a specific webpage and I'm trying to set it so that it always opens in a new window/instance of the browser, instead of just opening a new tab in my current instance.

This is on Firefox if it matters.

Answer (score 2):

#### I'm trying to set it so that it always opens in a new window/instance of the browser

Edit your shortcut to include the `-new-window` command line option:

> `-new-window URL`
>
> Open `URL in a new window. Firefox and SeaMonkey2.x only.

Source: [Command line options - Mozilla | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options#Browser)

Comment: I found that before posting and when I tried it there's no success. I do wonder if part of it is the way I'm creating the shortcut. From the webpage I'm simply pulling it to my desktop as described [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/create-desktop-shortcut-website), when I try to change the URL to `-new-window URL` it simply updates the URL to be a web search.

Comment: You don't change the URL, you add it to the command line after `Firefox`